# Private inheritance from std::basic_string

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

I've been trying to learn more about private inheritance and decided to create a `string_t` class that inherits from `std::basic_string`. I know a lot of you will tell me inheriting from STL classes is a bad idea and that it's better to just create global functions that accept references to instances of these classes if I want to extend their functionality. I agree, but like I said earlier, I'm trying to learn how to implement private inheritance.

This is what the class looks like so far:

```
class string_t :
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
  private std::basic_string<wchar_t>
#else
  private std::basic_string<char>
#endif
{
public:
  string_t() : basic_string<value_type>() {}

  string_t( const basic_string<value_type>& str ) 
    : basic_string<value_type>( str ) {}

  virtual ~string_t() {}

  using std::basic_string<value_type>::operator=; /* Line causing error */

  std::vector<string_t> split( const string_t& delims )
  {
    std::vector<string_t> tokens;

    tokens.push_back( substr( 0, npos ) );
  }
};
```

I get the following errors:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility(3133) : error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'const string_t *' to 'const std::basic_string &' exists, but is inaccessible
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=wchar_t,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator
1>        ]

1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility(3161) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Fill(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=string_t,
1>            _FwdIt=string_t *
1>        ]

1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vector(1229) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::fill(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=string_t,
1>            _FwdIt=string_t *
1>        ]

1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vector(1158) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector::_Insert_n(std::_Vector_const_iterator,unsigned int,const _Ty &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=string_t,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator
1>        ]

1>        c:\work\c++\string_t\string_t.h(658) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=string_t
1>        ]
```

The line number (658) in the last error points to the opening brace of the `split()` function definition. I can get rid of the error if I comment out the `using std::basic_string<value_type>::operator=;` line. As I understand it, the `using` keyword specifies that the assignment operator is being brought from `private` to `public` scope within `string_t`.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Also, my `string_t` class doesn't contain a single data member of it's own, much less any dynamically allocated members. So if I don't create a destructor for this class doesn't that mean that if someone were to `delete` an instance of `string_t` using a base class pointer the base class destructor would be called?

The following code throws an exception when I have a destructor defined for `string_t` but works when I comment out the destructor when compiled with VS2008.

```
basic_string<wchar_t> *p = new string_t( L"Test" );
delete p;
```

Comment: don't you think you'd learn more about private inheritance by using it for something where you *don't* have to ignore everyone's advice? ;)

Comment: Private inheritance is usually a bad idea. The only reason to ever use it is to have the `EBO` optimization apply (Empty Base Optimization), and since `std::string` has data, it does not qualify. All the other "reasons" (like virtual redefinition) have other solutions (in this precise case, public inheritance + composition). Inheritance is a very strong relationship, notably in term of visibility, it's better than friendship, but not by much. And for this problem, you can perfectly add free-functions to extend an interface.

Comment: @Matthieu - the problem with public inheritance in this case is that std::basic_string does not have a virtual destructor; so trying to delete an instance of string_t using a base class pointer would result in a memory leak. Maybe you can answer the second question: if the string_t class doesn't need a destructor and doesn't declare one, does the problem I mentioned with delete still exist?

Comment: @praetorian: You are correct that if `string`'s destructor is sufficient, there shouldn't be an issue. By the way, your code compiles for me. I also fleshed it out and tested it; everything should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default constructor should not be explicit. I think explicitness may be the reason it can't convert `std::string` to `string_t` as well, but you erased that construtor from your snippet :vP .

This program compiles and runs fine with GCC 4.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class string_t :
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
  private std::basic_string<wchar_t>
#else
  private std::basic_string<char>
#endif
{
public:
  string_t() : basic_string<value_type>() {}

  string_t( const basic_string<value_type>& str )
    : basic_string<value_type>( str ) {}

  virtual ~string_t() {}

  using std::basic_string<value_type>::operator=; /* Line causing error */

  std::vector<string_t> split( const string_t& delims )
  {
    std::vector<string_t> tokens;

    for ( size_t pen = 0, next = 0; next != npos; pen = next + 1 ) {
        next = find_first_of( delims, pen );
        if ( pen != next ) tokens.push_back( substr( pen, next - pen ) );
    }
    return tokens;
  }

  template<class os>
  friend os &operator<<(os &, string_t const&);
};

template< class os_t >
os_t &operator<<( os_t &os, string_t const &str ) {
        return os << static_cast< string >(str);
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
        vector<string_t> mytoks = string_t( argv[1] ).split( string( "_" ) );

        for ( vector<string_t>::iterator it = mytoks.begin(); it != mytoks.end(); ++ it ) {
                cerr << * it << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and tried to compile it but VS2008 gives me the same error!

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a suitable conversion constructor:

```
 string_t(const std::basic_string<value_type>&);
```

Otherwise the compiler doesn't know how to construct a `string_t` from a `std::basic_string<>` when you're adding elements to the vector of `string_t`s.

Regarding the update:
A `using` declaration for `operator=()` doesn't help if it is private. Why not just implement your own `operator=()` instead and forward the assignment:

```
string_t& operator=(const string_t& s) 
{
    basic_string<value_type>::operator=(s); 
    return *this; 
}
```

With that it builds fine for me.

Comment: I already have that constructor defined as follows:

    string_t(const std::basic_string<value_type>&) : basic_string<value_type>() {}

(Sorry, but I'm relatively new to templates, so I might be missing something obvious)

Comment: Why not give us a small compilable example that exhibits the problem then? Adding the conversion constructor makes the code compilable for me and doesn't show the first problem you're mentioning.

Comment: The conversion should NOT be private. He's getting problems because "conversion exists, but is inaccessible" ;v)

Comment: @gf - I've posted a compilable example that shows the error, as well as tracked down the line that's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you've left out enough that it's uncertain how you're getting the error message you've noted (and it doesn't help that we don't know what was line 657 when you compiled it...).

The probably currently appears to be that `substr()` is returning an std::string, and the compiler isn't sure how to convert that to a `string_t` (which is what you're asking it to store in the vector). You probably need/want to add a ctor to handle this, something like:

```
string_t(std::string const &init) : std::string(init) {}
```

That lets the compiler know how to convert the string returned by `substr()` into a `string_t` that it can push into the vector as you requested.

Comment: Sorry about the line numbers, line 657 is the line where the split() function is defined, it's the line containing the opening brace to be precise.  

I have a conversion constructor defined as follows:  

string_t(const std::basic_string<value_type>&) : basic_string<value_type>() {}   

Shouldn't that be the same as what you've said?

Comment: No, that accepts a `std::basic_string<value_type>` as a parameter, but fails to pass the parameter through to the base class.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. The constructor is actually defined as:    string_t( const basic_string<value_type>& str )  
    : basic_string<value_type>( str ) {}